# Update ssh for Kubuntu 14.4

Tags: ssh, upgrade, kubuntu

I am using Kubuntu 14.4 and have

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

installed. I have trouble to log in into some servers I need to get into and the support thinks, it is because my ssh is too old. How can I upgrade my ssh version to the current version (openssh-7.5p1 if I am not mistaken) without destroying my OS? The support said it might be possible to install ssh 7.5 seperately using the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Use apt-get? Is your version of ssh package managed?

Comment: @RamanSailopal: Kubuntu 14.4 is from 2014. So ssh in the repos is old (as old as mentioned in the question).

Comment: Best thing I would suggest would be to create a test environment, build the latest version of ssh from source and verify that everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Like @RamanSailopal said, the best thing would be to create a test environment and build the latest from source.

```
cd /tmp
wget ftp://ftp3.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-7.5p1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf openssh-7.5p1.tar.gz
cd openssh-7.5p1
./configure
make
make install
```

However, I suggest you upgrade from `14.4` to the latest version of `Kubuntu`, not the best idea to use "End of life" OS's.

Comment: How do I build the test environment?

Comment: A virtual machine is one option.